# python required fields from input file

Tags: python, regex

I have an input file I am using for a python script.

Example of a file is here:

```
Name:       Joe
Surname:     Doe
Country:     DE
Gender:
```

Anybody would suggest how to parse the file and make sure that all required info is supplied?
I am trying to avoid if/else statements and trying to implement in more efficient way!

Here is what I do but I am sure there is a better way.

```py
for line in file_content:
      if re.match(r'Name\d+:\s+(\w+)', line, re.IGNORECASE):
         file_validation['name'] = True
      elif  re.match(r'Surname:\s+(\w+)', line, re.IGNORECASE):
         file_validation['surname'] = True
      ...
```

Any suggestions?
ZDZ

Comment: define ' required info'

Comment: What type of file is it?  It doesn't really make sense to use regex in your example.  You are better off parsing the file as yaml or json, then asserting that the required fields are included.

Comment: thanks for tip Monica. Its text file but for now I will have to stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(.+)\s*:\s*(.*)$', 'Surname:     Doe').groups()                                
('Surname', 'Doe')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using csvreader because of its simplicity:

```
import csv

fields_to_validate = ["name", "surname", "country", "gender"]

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':')
    for row in csv_reader:
        field_key = row[0].lower()
        field_value = row[1].strip()
        print("\n{} {}".format(field_key, field_value))
        if field_key in fields_to_validate and field_value:
            print("{} validated correctly!".format(field_key))
        else:
            print("{} NOT validated correctly.".format(field_key))
```

**Output**

```
name Joe
name validated correctly!

surname Doe
surname validated correctly!

country DE
country validated correctly!

gender
gender NOT validated correctly.
```

Comment: Nice tip Pitto.  I was not even thinking about csv module!

Comment: If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should parse using regex and construct a dict from the file. The regex we'll be using is-

```regex
^(\w+):\s+(\w+)$
```

This will only select **combinations of key and values**. So it will not match `Gender:`  since it is empty.

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO4ZBg/1)

Now we just have to construct a corresponding dictionary

```py
# File contents
content = '''Name:       Joe
Surname:     Doe
Country:     DE
Gender:   
'''
data = {k:v for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w+):\s+(\w+)', content, re.M)}
```

Now if you look at data, it should look like-

```
>>> data
{'Name': 'Joe', 'Surname': 'Doe', 'Country': 'DE'}
```

Now all you have to do, is verify all the *required fields* exist in `data.keys()`

Initialize the required fields

```py
required_fields = {'Name', 'Surname', 'Country', 'Gender'}
```

Check if `required_fields` is a subset of `data.keys()` - if you want to allow extra keys in input, or, use `==` if you want only valid keys to exist in `data.keys()`.

```py
>>> set.issubset(required_fields, set(data.keys()))
False
>>> data.keys() == required_fields
False
```

Let's try the same thing with valid data-

```py
# File contents
content = '''Name:       Joe
Surname:     Doe
Country:     DE
Gender:     Male'''
required_fields = {'Name', 'Surname', 'Country', 'Gender'}

data = {k:v for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w+):\s+(\w+)', content, re.M)}
print(data.keys() == required_fields)    # True
print(set.issubset(required_fields, set(data.keys())))   # True
```

Output-

```
True
True
```

Comment: nice Chase, thx!